# How to calculate break even price of Bull Put Spread and Bear Call Spread

Tags: options

I need some help confirming if I am calculating the break even price correctly for both Bear Call Spread and Bull Put Spread.

For Bear Call Spread, I have:

```
breakEvenPrice = longLegStrike+(longLegCost-shortLegCost)
```

For Bull Put Spread, I have:

```
breakEvenPrice = longLegStrike+(longLegCost-shortLegCost)
```

Would these equation be correct?  It seem for both they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

The potential problem with your formulas is that long legs are debits and short legs are credits.  So longLegCost is a negative number.

An easier way is that the risk of a debit spread is its cost. For example, for an $85/$90 bull call spread that costs $3, the BE is $88.

The risk of a credit spread is the difference in strikes less the premium received. For example, for an $85/$90 bull put spread with a credit of $2, the BE is also $88.

Both have the potential to make $2 and the potential to lose $3.

Adjust your formulas accordingly.

Comment: Hey, I got it to work now, mostly through trail and error, it was very complicated but at the end the result match the expected values perfectly.